# how to keep blank result for Nokogiri's NodeSet.search method

Tags: ruby, search, nokogiri

i want to run the search method of Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet based on one NodeSet called nodeset for some xpath rule like below:

```
nodeset.search(rule)
```

the above code returns a NodeSet, but that doesn't contain the ones which can not match the rule. My intention is that: if element in nodeset is matched the rule, ok please return the matched result; if not matched please return a blank string in the result, so that i can know which element in caller nodeset is matched, which element in caller nodeset is not matched.

Could someone tell me how to do it? i will appreciate your help very much.

Comment: Thank you for all your reply very much, i know your meaning. I can treat the caller "nodeset" as an array and loop through one by one element to search the xpath "rule", but the result of search for each element is NodeSet, after looping through all the nodeset, i have a list of new nodesets, but finally i expect the final result is just a nodeset like the returned result of Nokogiri search method and with empty Node for ones which can not be matched the rule, instead of a list of nodeset which even though contain matched and not matched.

Comment: What is an "empty Node"? You are almost certainly going to have to use `select` or `map` per the answers below to create an Array and then manually create a new `NodeSet` yourself afterwards. If you need help with this, please clarify what you really expect to be present in the NodeSet to reflect your non-matches. So far you have said "blank string" and "empty Node".

Comment: @Phrogz thank you for your reply. yes, you all right. i can create my new NodeSet, then according to the specific search result to fill the NodeSet, that's cool. Really appreciate all your helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nokogiri `NodeSet` support set operations similar to Ruby arrays. Instead of keeping blanks in your matched set, find out the missed items after the fact:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML <<-ENDXML
<root>
  <a id="a1" class="foo">
    <a id="a1a" class="foo" />
    <a id="a1b" class="foo" andalso="this" />
  </a>
  <a id="a2" class="foo" andalso="this">
    <a id="a2a" class="bar" />
    <a id="a2b" class="bar" andalso="this" />
  </a>
  <a id="a3" class="foo" andalso="this" />
</root>
ENDXML

foos = doc.xpath('//a[@class="foo"]')
p foos.map{ |e| e['id'] }
#=> ["a1", "a1a", "a1b", "a2"]

subselect = foos.xpath('self::*[@andalso="this"]')
p subselect.map{ |e| e['id'] }
#=> ["a1b", "a2", "a3"]

missed = foos - subselect
p missed.map{ |e| e['id'] }
#=> ["a1", "a1a"]
```

If you really want non-nodes in the result, you'll have to use `#map` instead of `#search` or other Nokogiri methods and get an `Array` instead of a `NodeSet`:

```
subselect = foos.map do |el|
  if el['andalso']=='this'
    el
  else
    ""
  end
end
p subselect.map{ |e| e=="" ? "" : e['id'] }
#=> ["", "", "a1b", "a2", "a3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know nokogiri well enough to know how well this will work but I suspect the following example may suggest a way forward. The following assumes that NodeSet behaves like a ruby array which it does according to its API docs [1]

```
a = (0..9).to_a
 => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
evens = a.select { |i| i % 2 == 0 }
 => [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
odds = a - evens
 => [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

I believe you should be able to do something similar with your nodeset so that when your search has been performed, you can find the non-matched nodes by subtracting the new nodeset from the original one.

[1] http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#M000448

Comment: Thank you for your reply, your pointed direction is also right, but i can only select one, anyway thank you.

Comment: You can upvote though ;-) Actually I agree, Phrogz's solution is the same as mine but better explained.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd go about it:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = <<EOT
<xml>
  <find_node>foo</find_node>
  <ignore_node>bar</ignore_node>
  <find_node>foo</find_node>
  <ignore_node>bar</ignore_node>
</xml>
EOT

# parse the document...
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)

# find the nodes we want...
desired_nodes = doc.search('//find_node')

# see if it's working...
desired_nodes.map{ |n| n.to_xml } # => ["<find_node>foo</find_node>", "<find_node>foo</find_node>"]

# walk the tree, grabbing the text or '' depending on whether the node is a hit or a miss...
node_result = doc.search('/xml/*').map{ |n| desired_nodes.include?(n) ? n.text : '' }

# ** here's the result **
node_result # => ["foo", "", "foo", ""]
```

---

```
# if we wanted to we could grab the desired_nodes' text...
desired_nodes.map{ |n| n.text } # => ["foo", "foo"]

# or find the ignored nodes...
ignored_nodes = doc.search('/xml/*') - desired_nodes
ignored_nodes.map{ |n| n.to_xml } # => ["<ignore_node>bar</ignore_node>", "<ignore_node>bar</ignore_node>"]

# ...and grab the ignored_nodes' text...
ignored_nodes.map{ |n| n.text } # => ["bar", "bar"]
```